# Unable to filter Array of objects having dynamic keys using dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I want to filter this array of object based on **EmployeeStatus** which should be only **Resigned and Terminated** but not **active**. Here the keys are different for each object and hence I am unable to apply logic like `item.key.EmployeeStaus=="Resigned" or "Terminated"` .Any suggestions or hint would be helpful for me.

**Input Payload**

```
[
  {
    "626433000000196190": [
      {
        "EmailID": "rubyrichards@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Resigned"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196184": [
      {
        "EmailID": "morganfinely@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Active"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196178": [
      {
        "EmailID": "jenniferjackson@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Active"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196166": [
      {
        "EmailID": "daveduken@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Terminated"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Required Output**

```
[
  {
        "EmailID": "rubyrichards@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Resigned"
  },
  {
        "EmailID": "daveduken@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Terminated
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

**Input**

```
[
  {
    "626433000000196190": [
      {
        "EmailID": "rubyrichards@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Resigned"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196184": [
      {
        "EmailID": "morganfinely@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Active"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196178": [
      {
        "EmailID": "jenniferjackson@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Active"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196166": [
      {
        "EmailID": "daveduken@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Terminated"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
flatten(payload   map 
     ($  mapObject {
          b: $ filter ($.Employeestatus != "Active") 
     }).b -[])
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "EmailID": "rubyrichards@zylker.com",
    "Employeestatus": "Resigned"
  },
  {
    "EmailID": "daveduken@zylker.com",
    "Employeestatus": "Terminated"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another take:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var data = [
  {
    "626433000000196190": [
      {
        "EmailID": "rubyrichards@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Resigned"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196184": [
      {
        "EmailID": "morganfinely@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Active"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196178": [
      {
        "EmailID": "jenniferjackson@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Active"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196166": [
      {
        "EmailID": "daveduken@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Terminated"
      }
    ]
  }
]
---
flatten({(data)} pluck $) filter not ($.Employeestatus == "Active")
```

I 'll add explanations later on.

EDIT: Here's the explanation and links to the DW documentation:

1. I make use of the [dynamic elements](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#dynamic_elements) feature `{(data)}` to destroy the array and collapse all enclosed objects into an object.
2. I then use [`pluck`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-pluck) to get just the values in an array.
3. I make use of [`flatten`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-flatten) to collapse the first level of sub-arrays, because the values we just `pluck`ed are also arrays.  You now have a flat array.
4. Now I make use of [`filter`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-filter) to remove eliminate all records that fail the assertion to the right.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the records by transversing the structure. First an array, using map. Each element is an object with a single key, so let's use mapObject, then filter. I didn't try to remove the empty arrays.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
fun filterEmployeeStatus(e) = e filter ($.Employeestatus == "Resigned" or $.Employeestatus == "Terminated")
---
payload map 
    ( $ mapObject ((value, key, index) -> (key): filterEmployeeStatus(value) ) )
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "626433000000196190": [
      {
        "EmailID": "rubyrichards@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Resigned"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196184": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196178": [
      
    ]
  },
  {
    "626433000000196166": [
      {
        "EmailID": "daveduken@zylker.com",
        "Employeestatus": "Terminated"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hey @aled.. By any means cant we remove the keys present??..Those keys are no more nescessary for me..I just wanted to eliminate the complexity of array present in between so that for further manipulation it will be easier for me to use the resultant payload which is the required output as I showed above in question..Just am curious to know if its possible or not

Comment: pluck $ at the end of the script should help you achieve that.